# chaquopy build package Error: Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel

Tags: python-wheel, chaquopy

I am trying to build a newer version of numpy into a whl file with the chaquopy build package tool, every dependencies work now, however i get this error:

```
raise SystemError("One of the required function to build numpy is not"
SystemError: One of the required function to build numpy is not available (the list is ['sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'sinh', 'cosh', 'tanh', 'fabs', 'floor', 'ceil', 'sqrt', 'log10', 'log', 'exp', 'asin', 'acos', 'atan', 'fmod', 'modf', 'frexp', 'ldexp', 'expm1', 'log1p', 'acosh', 'asinh', 'atanh', 'rint', 'trunc', 'exp2', 'copysign', 'nextafter', 'strtoll', 'strtoull', 'cbrt', 'log2', 'pow', 'hypot', 'atan2', 'creal', 'cimag', 'conj']).
build-wheel: Error: Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
```

Comment: This will require more detailed discussion, and StackOverflow is not designed for that. So please create an issue on the [Chaquopy GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues), and make sure you include (1) the complete build log, not just the last few lines, and (2) exactly what changes you've made to the NumPy recipe.